# $TM\simeq M\times\mathbb{R}^n \Rightarrow M$ is orientable

Tags: geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, orientation

> If $M$ is a smooth, parallelizable manifold, then it is orientable.

From the definition I know, $M$ is said to be parallelizable when there is a diffeomorphism $\phi:TM\to M\times\mathbb{R}^n$ which is linear on the fibers.

What I'm trying to do is to take an orientation of $TM$ and somehow induce an orientation on $M\times\mathbb{R}^n$, which somehow would induce an orientation on $M$.

But I don't know if we always have an orientation on $TM$ and even if there is, I'm having trouble formalizing the iduced orientation.

Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: That is not the definition of parallelizability. If M is parallelizable, then TM is indeed diffeomorphic to what you say but the converse is either not true or not trivial to prove.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, I've found this definition in Loring W. Tu's Introduction to smooth manifolds: "A manifold whose tangent bundle is trivial is said to be parallelizable"

Comment: Yes, *that* is a correct definition. It is quite different from what you wrote in your question, though! That a vector bundle $E$ on a manifold $M$ be trivial does not mean that $E$ be diffeomorphic to $M\times\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Since we are talking about smooth manifolds, I think saying $TM$ is a trivial vector bundle implicitly means $TM$ and $M\times\mathbb{R}^n$ are diffeomorphic, doesn't it? Anyway, I think we understand each other :)

Comment: No, it does not meant that, implicitly or explicitly. It is true that $TM$ being a trivial vector bundle **implies** that it is diffeomorphic to $M\times\mathbb R^n$ but it is simply **false** that «$M$ is said to be parallelizable when $TM$ and $M\times\mathbb{R}^n$ are diffeomorphic manifolds», as you wrote in your question. I don't think we are understanding each other, for otherwise you would have corrected your question by now.

Comment: To say that $TM$ is trivial means that there is a diffeomorphism $TM \to M \times \Bbb R^n$ that is *linear on the fibers*. That's a pretty big condition.

Comment: Thanks, @MikeMiller, that's the condition I was missing!

Comment: Yes, it is true dat $TM$ is always orientable. For charts $\phi,\psi$ of $M$ and corresponding induced charts $\tilde\phi,\tilde\psi$ of $TM$, $\tilde\psi\circ\tilde\phi^{-1}$ has determinant $\det(\psi\circ\phi^{-1})^2$ (one factor coming from the action on $M$, the other from the linear action on the fibers).